# Set tag of a ListBox item

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is it possible to set the `Tag` property of an individual item of the `ListBox` instead of only the whole control?

I tried

```
listbox.Items(i).Tag = "Test"
```

Unfortunately without any luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not how ListBox works.  It doesn't have a dedicated item type like TreeView or ListView has, there is no ListBoxItem class.  So there's no Tag property either.

ListBox is far more general, it accepts *any* object in its Items.Add() method.  The rule is that whatever object you add needs to override the ToString() method.  That's what ListBox uses to display the text for the item.  Which then also removes the need for a Tag property.  Just cast the object you get back from, say, `listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex]` back to your class type.

Do consider ListView if that's hard to deal with, setting its View property to List gets you a list box too.  With a Tag property for the ListViewItems you add.

Comment: You say there is no ListBoxItemClass.  Microsoft contradicts you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listboxitem(v=vs.110).aspx  and even better, it has a tag property.  Try again, Hans.

Comment: PresentationFramework is a WPF assembly of course, this is a Winforms question. Try again @Obi.