# Visual Basic 2008 - Getting a certain value from a listbox and displaying in a textbox

Tags: vb.net, string, listbox

i've been trying to do this for awhile but i'm not sure.

For an example, The listbox contents are:

```
id = 0 - Block
id = 1 - Cow
```

What I want is to get only the id number to be displayed onto a textbox

So for a textbox, it would appear like this:

```
0
1
```

Without the other stuff.

Thanks everyone :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set tag of a ListBox item](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466298/set-tag-of-a-listbox-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe:

```
Dim s = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
s = s.replace("id =","")  'remove "id ="
s = s.Substring(0,s.IndexOf("-")-1).Trim() 'truncate s from the start to the "-"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could also use:

```
Dim id = Split(listbox.SelectedItem.ToString(),"-")(0)
```

and then do your replace:

```
id = id.Replace("id = ","")
```

### or

```
id = listbox.SelectedItem.ToString()
id = id.Substring(id.IndexOf("=") +1), id.IndexOf("-") -1)
```

The +1 and -1 are to move beyond a space and stop before a space.

Both of these solutions require 2 less method calls, which if I'm not mistaken, means creating two less copies of a string in memory, doing what you're doing. Don't quote me on that last part, though. =)

Comment: You technically don't have to set a variable to the .ToString'ed item. I just did that for readability.